# "Temporarily" redirecting stdin

Tags: bash, stdin, zsh

I want to redirect stdin to be from a file, but then, once it finishes with that file, to make stdin from a keyboard.  I do know how to redirect stdin regularly, I just don't know how to switch back.  I currently use zsh, and am not willing to switch, but tagged with bash because I’m not averse to writing scripts in bash.

Comment: I thought about it some, but the only solution I could come up with was  `foo < =(cat bar; while true; read i; echo $i; done)`,  But I realized that this wouldn't work because it would try to readin forever and _then_ run foo.

Comment: OK, in zsh I get: `zsh: parse error near 'done'
zsh: parse error in process substitution`  And in bash, `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

Answer (score 1):

To execute `foo` with input from file `bar` and then from the keyboard, use:

```
cat bar - | foo
```

When the user is done typing, he has to type ctrl-D on a new line to signal the end of his input.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't really what I want.  I want to see the output of the screen in live time: I intend to use this primarily for ssh connections, where I will be running a shell, so this won't really work.  But thanks for answering,

Comment: @Accidentalbrine So what are you really trying to do?  Do you want to execute some commands under `ssh` and then do interactive work?  Or, what?

Comment: @john10249: I want to automatically log in to a nethack server and then go into interactive mode so I can play.

Comment: @Accidentalbrine That sounds like a job for the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) utility.  Expect can issue commands, wait for prompts, send responses.  [Here is an example](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94334/script-to-login-to-ssh-twice), possibly more complex than you need, of using expect to login to a remote service which you can then use interactively.  The details of the prompts and response will, of course, have to be adjusted depending how your nethack server operates.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really too broad to be answered exhaustively, but here is one technique which satisfies your stated requirements.

```
{ some commands; other commands; } <file
more commands   # read stdin
```

You can do something similar with `exec` and/or saved file descriptors (temporarily duplicate file descriptor 0, redirect, then restore from the duplicated file descriptor) but the above does the same thing fairly transparently.

If your requirements are different, please update your question to properly describe your problem.

Comment: I'm unsure how to make this work.  How do I read the "more commands"?  Currently I have `{ssh myserver; nethack} < =(echo mypassword)`, but this isn't working satisfactorily.  How do I read the `more commands`?

Comment: If you want to automate the password prompt specifically, that's much better handled by setting up passwordless `ssh` login. Google [`ssh` public key authentication](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+public+key+authentication)